Transposing Subdaily Climate Data
I have precipitation data collected in 5 minutes time steps as presented in CSV format as below.
DateTime,PR00,PR05,PR10,PR15,PR20,PR25,PR30,PR35,PR40,PR45,PR50,PR55
12/31/2013 0:00,0,0.4,0.6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0.6,0
12/31/2013 1:00,0,0.4,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.6,1.2,0.4,0,0.2,0,0.4
12/31/2013 2:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/31/2013 3:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/31/2013 4:00,0,0.2,0,0,0,0,0,0.2,0,0,0,0
12/31/2013 5:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
12/31/2013 6:00,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

The link to the CSV file is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14diXLS4jPt-rkAPG1xZAke1PgnBkuO0y/view?usp=sharing
The first column is date with time in 1 hr time step (rows), the columns are precipitation records at five (5) minutes time sptep for each hour. I would like to create a data frame of two columns of date (time) and the precipitation as follows:
Date,Precip
12/31/2013 0:00,0
12/31/2014 0:05,0.4
12/31/2015 0:10,0.6
12/31/2013 0:15,0
12/31/2013 0:20,0
12/31/2013 0:25,0
12/31/2013 0:30,0
12/31/2013 0:35,0
12/31/2013 0:40,0
12/31/2013 0:45,0.2
12/31/2013 0:50,0.6
12/31/2013 0:55,0
12/31/2013 1:00,0
12/31/2013 1:05,0.4
12/31/2013 1:10,0.4
12/31/2013 1:15,0.2
12/31/2013 1:20,0.6
12/31/2013 1:25,0.6
12/31/2013 1:30,1.2
12/31/2013 1:35,0.4
12/31/2013 1:40,0
12/31/2013 1:45,0.2
12/31/2013 1:50,0
12/31/2013 1:55,0.4
12/31/2013 2:00,0
12/31/2013 2:05,0
12/31/2013 2:10,0
12/31/2013 2:15,0
12/31/2013 2:20,0
12/31/2013 2:25,0
12/31/2013 2:30,0
12/31/2013 2:35,0
12/31/2013 2:40,0
12/31/2013 2:45,0
12/31/2013 2:50,0
12/31/2013 2:55,0
12/31/2013 3:00,0
12/31/2013 3:05,0
12/31/2013 3:10,0
12/31/2013 3:15,0
12/31/2013 3:20,0
12/31/2013 3:25,0
12/31/2013 3:30,0
12/31/2013 3:35,0
12/31/2013 3:40,0
12/31/2013 3:45,0
12/31/2013 3:50,0
12/31/2013 3:55,0
12/31/2013 4:00,0
12/31/2013 4:05,0.2
12/31/2013 4:10,0
12/31/2013 4:15,0
12/31/2013 4:20,0
12/31/2013 4:25,0
12/31/2013 4:30,0
12/31/2013 4:35,0.2
12/31/2013 4:40,0
12/31/2013 4:45,0.2
12/31/2013 4:50,0
12/31/2013 4:55,0
12/31/2013 5:00,0
12/31/2013 5:05,0
12/31/2013 5:10,0
12/31/2013 5:15,0
12/31/2013 5:20,0
12/31/2013 5:25,0
12/31/2013 5:30,0
12/31/2013 5:35,0
12/31/2013 5:40,0
12/31/2013 5:45,0
12/31/2013 5:50,0
12/31/2013 5:55,0
12/31/2013 6:00,0
12/31/2013 6:05,0
12/31/2013 6:10,0
12/31/2013 6:15,0
12/31/2013 6:20,0
12/31/2013 6:25,0
12/31/2013 6:30,0
12/31/2013 6:35,0
12/31/2013 6:40,0
12/31/2013 6:45,0
12/31/2013 6:50,0
12/31/2013 6:55,0


A tidyverse solution:
pivot_longer(df, -DateTime) |>
  mutate(name=as.numeric(sub("PR", "", name)),
         DateTime=DateTime+60*name) |>
  select(-name)
# A tibble: 84 × 2
   DateTime            value
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 2013-12-31 00:00:00   0  
 2 2013-12-31 00:05:00   0.4
 3 2013-12-31 00:10:00   0.6
 4 2013-12-31 00:15:00   0  
 5 2013-12-31 00:20:00   0  
 6 2013-12-31 00:25:00   0  
 7 2013-12-31 00:30:00   0  
 8 2013-12-31 00:35:00   0  
 9 2013-12-31 00:40:00   0  
10 2013-12-31 00:45:00   0.2
# ℹ 74 more rows


Data:
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1388419200, 1388422800, 
1388426400, 1388430000, 1388433600, 1388437200, 1388440800), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), PR00 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR05 = c(0.4, 
0.4, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0), PR10 = c(0.6, 0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR15 = c(0, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR20 = c(0, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR25 = c(0, 
0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR30 = c(0, 1.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR35 = c(0, 
0.4, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0), PR40 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR45 = c(0.2, 
0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR50 = c(0.6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PR55 = c(0, 
0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Edit: You may need to convert the DateTime column to a valid date/time class:
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") 

